# Ho to access the data from inside html table tags <table> and display it outside of table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, html-table

I am making an HTML form and using table inside the form. The data is displayed perfectly inside form but I want to access some data from the table and display it outside the table tag, how can I do that?
Your help is highly appreciated

The data on the page is displayed like this:

[image: this is how the table looks]

But I want something like this:
Access one of the columns out side table tags
[image: like this]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head> 
 <style>

.new {
    float:right; width:98%;
   margin-top:0;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
}

.descp{

background-color:lightgreen;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;

}
  
</style>
<br> 

<div class= "head new">

   <center> <h1> PROMOTION PROPOSAL </h1> </center>
 
    </div>

<div id="container" class="new">
<table table id="example"  class="table table-bordered table-striped " style="width:100%" >
    <col style="width:14%">
    <col style="width:9%">
    <col style="width:15%">
     <col style="width:8%">
    <col style="width:6%">
    <col style="width:6%">
     <col style="width:6%">
    <col style="width:6%">

  <thead>
<tr>
                <th colspan="5"></th>
                <th style="background-color:powderblue;text-align:center;"colspan="2">OFF INVOICE</th>
                <th style="background-color:powderblue;text-align:center;"colspan="3">RETROSPECTIVE</th>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
            </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>Product Code</th>
      <th>Outer Barcode</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Pack Size & Weight</th>
      <th>Standard Invoice Cost of Product</th>
      <th>Bonus</th>
      <th>Net Cost</th>
      <th>Retro Bonus</th>
   
      
    </tr>
     <tr>
                
                <th class="descp" colspan="1">Enterde in this column</th>
                <th class="descp" colspan="1">Enter your OUTER barcode in this column</th>
                <th class="descp" colspan="1">Enter the full product name with how you would like</th>
                <th class="descp" colspan="1">Pack size & weight in this box or numb</th>
                <th class="descp"colspan="1">Standard invoice cost of product</th>
                <th class="descp" colspan="1">Enter here how</th>
                <th class="descp" colspan="1">Net</th>

               
            </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="Off Invoice example -CRG123" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="50212341234" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="Brand Name Crunchy Cornflakes" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="£25 x 250g" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="£3.05" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="£0.5" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="£2.55" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="" required></td>
      

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="Retro Example - CRG321" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="50312341234" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="Brand Name Large Jam Tart" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="1 x 10 Pre Portioned" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="£6.00" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name[0]" placeholder="£0.50" required></td>
     
    </tr>
   
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: The second screenshot is cut off, Please update when you get a chance. 
Are you trying to move the column headings from one to the other or completely outside the table?

Comment: Use `.value()` to get the value of the input you want, then use `.text()` to display it in a DIV outside the table.

Comment: @Ramakay I I am trying to display information from one of the columns in table and display that information outside the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code sample provided, i did not see any JS code but includes of jQuery and popper.js so i am assuming none has been attempted, we can revise the answer if you have attempted something already and enhance it.

There are multiple ways to do this but one way could be:

1. Setup identifiers in the table heading e.g: `<th id='retro-bonus'...>`
2. Setup a script that fires on load of the document
3. Setup a `div` or another element prior to the table
4. you can get the `element.innerText` or `element.innerHTML` (if you need the formatting ) in your script, where `element` is the `th`.
5. set the `innerHTML` or `innerText` of your div

If you have more items, set more corresponding divs. If you need these on top of each of the columns in a particular location, it gets tricky but can be accomplished using something like a css grid.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you! when giving the id  inside <th> :<th id='retro-bonus'> and using 
    <script>
function getInnerText() {
  alert(document.getElementById("p_code").innerText)
}   Only name of header gets displaye. I want value inside the <td> tag and when using the ame id inside <td> tag it displays nothing

Comment: Please post the code in your original answer so we can help you further.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it. by using  <script>
  var x = document.getElementById("myid").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script> and then called this in div tag by : <div id="container1">

<p id="demo"></p>


</div>